# How can I make assert_eq! in Rust show multiline strings

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust unit test:

```
    #[test]
    fn test_multiline_strings_are_equal() {
        let expected = "\
one
two
three
four
";
        let actual = "\
one
two
four
";
        assert_eq!(actual, expected);
    }
```

When it fails, it outputs the following:

```
---- printer::tests::test_multiline_strings_are_equal stdout ----
thread 'printer::tests::test_multiline_strings_are_equal' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"one\ntwo\nfour\n"`,
 right: `"one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n"`', src\printer.rs:600:9
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it show "one", "two", "three" and "four" on separate lines, for easier comparison?

Comment: You could look at [pretty_assertions](https://crates.io/crates/pretty_assertions) crate. It redefines standard assert macros, that have more human readable diff output.

Answer (score 7):

The [`pretty_assertions`](https://docs.rs/pretty_assertions/) library does this. Just add

```rust
use pretty_assertions::assert_eq;
```

and its replacement `assert_eq!` macro will produce a line-by-line diff; in your example:

```
Diff < left / right > :
 one
 two
>three
 four
```

It also works with the `Debug` output of non-string values:

```rust
use pretty_assertions::assert_eq;

#[test]
fn test_struct() {
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    struct Foo {
        x: &'static str,
        y: &'static str,
    }

    assert_eq!(
        Foo { x: "x", y: "y" },
        Foo {
            x: "x",
            y: "surprise!",
        }
    );
}
```

```
Diff < left / right > :
 Foo {
     x: "x",
<    y: "y",
>    y: "surprise!",
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. I tried writing my own macro; it worked, but was fiddly. Nice that someone else did that work already, and better!

Answer (score 3):

The [`assert_eq!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html) macro will *"print the values of the expressions with their debug representations"* if the values are not equal. This uses the `Debug` format specifier, which for strings will escape newlines and other control characters. So you can't override that without wrapping the strings in some type that makes the `Debug` implementation use the `Display` implementation.

An alternative though is the macro allows you to provide your own message using the normal formatting syntax. So you could provide the non-debug output as well:

```
assert_eq!(actual, expected, "\n expanded left: {actual}\nexpanded right: {expected}\n");
```

```
thread 'test_multiline_strings_are_equal' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"one\ntwo\nfour\n"`,
 right: `"one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n"`: 
 expanded left: one
two
four

expanded right: one
two
three
four

', src/lib.rs:14:5
```

It looks a bit weird since I don't think the macro was really expecting the custom message to have newlines (see the trailing `', src/lib.rs:14:5`) but it hopefully it works well enough.

If that's not good enough, it wouldn't be too hard to make your own macro.

Comment: Nice, thanks. That works, but I'll look into creating a macro as well.